# iOS POST with AFNetworking : NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have a UITextField and I want to update my server when I write something in UITextField and
press update button, I used AFNetworking, but I have an error :

```
 Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 
 "Request failed: internal server error (500)
{ status code: 500, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE";
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "text/plain";
Date = "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 00:41:56 GMT";
Server = Cowboy;
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
Via = "1.1 vegur";
"X-Powered-By" = Express;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)}
```

Here is my Update button code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];


NSDictionary *params = @ {@"status" :_status};


[manager POST:BASE_URL parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
 }
      failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

Appreciated any help!

Comment: It is a server error, so something is probably wrong on your server, not the client. Check your server logs to see what's going on. This is not an iOS issue.

Comment: Does your server expect Content-Type to be "text/plain" or "application/json" ? Your iOS code shows you're using AFJSONRequestSerializer (which will take your parameters and send them as JSON instead of plain text) but your server response says "Content-Type" should(?) be "text/plain" ?

Comment: @Zhang i have the exact problem, i know my server expects "text/plain"  but i cannot make acceptable my valid JSON by sending as NSDictionary. I'm getting the same error (Request failed: internal server error (500)). Then how can i make acceptable my json can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Error code, -1011 means `kCFURLErrorBadServerResponse` (from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/index.html)). Your web service (API) giving you response for which your request/response serializer of `AFNetworking` doesn't know. Ask your developer team to see and correct the error.

Answer (score -2):

Remove this line from your code:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

and change your requestSerializer to: `[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];`

This works fine in my application.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. You can't assign a request serializer to the response serializer of the manager.

Comment: didnt mean to assign request serializer to response serializer.